# How to convert Object in Array

Tags: html, arrays, object

I have a object and I can try to convert this object in a special array,

This is the index
`const index = 3`

This is my object
  `object = {           fruit: apple           vegetable: carrot           number: 5           color: red      }`

This is the array structure that I want to achieve
 `[       3: {                fruit: apple                vegetable: carrot                number: 5               color: red               }   ]`

I´m not expert in arrays but I try this and dont´t convert in array with the special structure

`this.object.entries(newObj).map(x => {       return index[x] })`

Please could you help me, I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a new array with required length and assign the object to required index

```js
const index = 3
const myObject = { fruit: 'apple', vegetable: 'carrot', number: 5, color: 'red' }
const op = new Array(index + 1);
op[index] = myObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```js
  let index = 1;
        let object = { fruit: 'apple', vegetable: 'carrot', number: 5, color: 'red' }
        let array = [];
        array.push(object)
        console.log(array);
```